# From where I need to download the dSYM from app store connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, dsym

I regularly download dSYM from the Activity tab in app store connect.

[image]

In that tab there are list of builds from their detail we can download the dSYMs.

But from today after After App Store Connect update, I have seen that there is no activity.

Apple [Thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668965) related to this topic.

[image]

So, From where I can download the dSYM?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found the way to download the dSYM

- Log in to App Store Connect, then click My Apps > TestFlight.
- Select the build you want to download a dSYM for.
- Click Build Metadata Tab > Download dSYM.

[image]

> Here I found a mail sent by the apple developer program support.
>
> I'm with Apple Developer Program Support. I’m following up with you
> regarding your recent email.
>
> I understand you are unable to locate the Activity tab in App Store
> Connect. I can certainly look into this for you. After researching
> your request, it looks like the **Activity tab has merged with the
> TestFlight tab in App Store Connect**. You can now see your **build
> metadata** under the TestFlight tab under your app record.

**Update (17th Dec 2020):**

Activity tab name changed to **Mac Build Activity**

[image]

**Update (04th Dec 2022):**

Find it under TestFlight Tab

[image]

Comment: Lifesaver +100. If you are like me, and your browser width is set to just the right width, the third column won't show, it wasn't obvious at first, just scroll to the right… Thanks Apple…

Comment: What to do if link to download dSym is missing? There is just text "Includes Symbols Yes" and empty space where link should be

Comment: Same happening with me like @YevgeniyLogachev mentioned. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to the Firebase docs, Apple only uploads dSYM for apps that are bitcode enabled (bitcode enabled builds are no longer possible with Xcode 14). So you'll need to get the dSYM from your local machine :\ https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=1#expandable-1

Comment: What if there is no local machine? My CI (AppCenter) is making those builds, and it deletes DSYMs when we finish the release and remove the release/ branch.

Comment: [Missing dSYM download link in App Store Connect](https://sarunw.com/posts/app-store-connect-download-dsym/)

Comment: @IgorVasilev di you ever found a solution?

Comment: @JohhanSantana we eventually switched from AppCenter to Bitrise - it stores all the DSYMs regardless of whether or not the branch was deleted, plus allows for easy integration of other services to upload them to (like Dynatrace or Firebase).

Answer (score 5):

I do not see a link next to "Include Symbols'...I was able to download the files using an instruction provided by flutter.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=1

Run the following to display all your dSYMs' UUIDs on your machine, then search for the missing dSYM:

mdfind -name .dSYM | while read -r line; do dwarfdump -u "$line"; done
Once you find the dSYM, upload it to Crashlytics. If the mdfind command doesn’t return any results, you can look in the Products directory where your .app lives (by default, the Products directory is located in Derived Data). If your app is released to production, you can also look for its dSYM in the .xcarchive directory on disk:

In Xcode, open the Organizer window and select your app from the list. Xcode displays a list of archives for your project.
Control-click an archive to view it in Finder. Then, control-click it again and click Show Package Contents.
Within .xcarchive is a dSYMs directory that contains dSYMs generated as part of Xcode’s archiving process. Recompiled bitcode dSYMs are also downloaded to this folder when you use the Download dSYMs... tool in the Organizer window.

Answer (score 5):

@Nathan Dudley

This 2 methods helped me find dSYM files

**First method to find dSYM-**

1. Navigate to-

/Users/{your_name}/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/{last archive date}/{app name + archive date}.xcarchive / dSYMs

2. look for the missing dSYM
3. insert to a new folder
4. compress that folder

**Second method -**

1. Go to Xcode MenuBar -> window -> Organizer
   (works with Xcode 13.2.1)
2. Right click on the last archive -> show in finder
3. Right click on fileName.xcarchive -> Show package content
   ￼
4. Look for the missing dSYM
   [image]
5. insert to a new folder
6. compress that folder

**Final stage -**
Upload to

[image]

Hope it helped !