# Activity tab not showing on itunesconnect.apple.com

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I logged in to my itunesconnect.apple.com after uploading a new build, and i am unable to see the **Activity** tab. Any idea where it goes or apple remove it?

Comment: Please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210768/from-where-i-need-to-download-the-dsym-from-app-store-connect hope it help you!

Answer (score 1):

The activity tab was removed on 12/8/2020. you can reach it:

1. My Apps.
2. TestFlight Tab.
3. Select any build.
4. New tab was added under each build "Build Metadata"

Or you can use the following URL:

"recent/activity/ios/builds?m=" to [https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/{app_id}](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/%7Bapp_id%7D)
so the final url:
[https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/{app_id}/recent/activity/ios/builds?m=](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps/%7Bapp_id%7D/recent/activity/ios/builds?m=)